# JS Lint Array Literal Notation with String Split

Tags: javascript, jslint

I know that JSLint is only a guide and you should take what it says with a grain of salt, however, I'm curious how I can even resolve this warning without rewriting the entire function. Here is the function of interest:

```
function randomString(length) {
    var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(''),
    str = '',
    i;

    if (!length) {
        length = randomNumber(chars.length);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str += chars[randomNumber(chars.length)];
    }
    return str;
}
```

JS Lint tells me "JS Lint: Use the array literal notation []." and it is pointing to the line with `string.split()`. How can I satisfy JSLint without having to re-write the entire function? Is it even possible?

I am aware that there are other methods to generate random strings; I'm interested in how to resolve the JSLint warning using this method.

Comment: You don't even need an array in that case, you could leave it as string and use `chars.charAt(...)`. Maybe that is sufficient to satisfy JSLint.

Comment: That's a good point and I might just change it to that eventually. However, I'd still like to know how JSLint expects me to use array literal notation in this particular instance.

Comment: Dunno, but here is the source ;) https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L3578

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the String prototype split function with the string as the scope to avoid the warning:

```
var chars = String.prototype.split.call('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''),
```

Don't know why JSLint complains as split is a String method.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

this also seems to pass through without complaints:

```
var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
chars = alphabet.split("");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is your Array in literal array-notation:

```
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'T', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
```

JSLint probably suggested it, because that way the Interpreter does not have to split the String during runtime, but rather has already the Array ready to use.

Simply generated with this PHP-Code:

```
php > $chars = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'); 
php > echo "[ '".implode("', '", $chars)."' ]";
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'T', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
php >
```

Comment: Why complicated PHP? Just type `JSON.stringify('ABC...xyz'.split(''))` in your browser's *javascript* console :-)